# Easy way to show with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

I have 6 functions in controllers to order by ASC and DESC 3fields.

Functions:

```
 public function orderByIdAsc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 

    }
    public function orderByIdDesc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 
    }
    public function orderByOrderAsc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('order','asc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 
    }
    public function orderByOrderDesc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('order','desc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 
    }
    public function orderByPublicAsc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('public','asc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 
    }
    public function orderByPublicDesc(){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy('public','desc')->get();
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu', ['projects' => $projects]); 
    }
```

With her 6 routes too:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('project/orderByIdAsc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByIdAsc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByIdAsc']);
        Route::get('project/orderByIdDesc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByIdDesc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByIdDesc']);
        Route::get('project/orderByOrderAsc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByOrderAsc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByOrderAsc']);
        Route::get('project/orderByOrderDesc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByOrderDesc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByOrderDesc']);
        Route::get('project/orderByPublicAsc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByPublicAsc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByPublicAsc']);
        Route::get('project/orderByPublicDesc', ['uses' => 'AdminController@orderByPublicDesc', 'as' => 'admin.projects.orderByPublicDesc']);
});
```

For the moment i call to the functions here:

```
<th><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByIdAsc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>Id<a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByIdDesc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
<th>Slug</th>
<th><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByOrderAsc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>Order<a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByOrderDesc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a></th>
<th><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByPublicAsc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>Public<a href="{{ route('admin.projects.orderByPublicDesc')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a></th>
```

Any way to do it with ajax easier than make 6 divs and hide / display it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do all of these return the same data, just ordered differently?  So your page is requesting the same data over and over?  Yes, there is an easier way to do it.  Request the data *once* and sort it as needed in JavaScript.  Or are you asking something else?  It's not really clear.

Comment: One of the option is to use `Route::get('project/orderBy/{field_name}/{asc_desc}` and get those arguments in Request. With this, you only need one route and one method.

Comment: Yes, is the same data ordered differently. Can you explain me how to do it with JS? thanks a lot

Comment: I will try it @MilanChheda give me 5minuts

Comment: @MilanChheda controllers function how have to looks like?

Comment: Numerous scripts around for sorting tables in browser using javascript. Far more user friendly also than reloading page

Comment: This are called wild cards. You will get them in 2 variables namely `$field_name` and `asc_desc`. So your method would be `public function method_name($field_name, $asc_desc)`

Comment: I think something is wrong. Now looking like this: `public function orderBy(field_name $asc_desc){
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy(field_name,$asc_desc)->get();
    }` know what's wrong? With 'wild cards' you want to say reserved words? @MilanChheda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you have two choices :

- **First one : using path parameters**

You can combine all the routes of ordering in one :

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('project/order/{field}/{order}', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@order', 
                'as' => 'admin.projects.order'
            ]);

});
```

In your `AdminController` :

```
public function order($field, $order) 
{
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy($field,$order)->get();
    return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu') 
               ->withProjects($projects);
}
```

In the view :

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id', 'order' => 'asc']) }}">Order by ID</a>
```

- **Second one : using query strings**

For the route :

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('project/order', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@order', 
                'as' => 'admin.projects.order'
            ]);

});
```

In your `AdminController` :

```
public function order(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) 
{
    $order = $request->query('order');
    $field = $request->query('field');
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->orderBy($field,$order)->get();
    return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu') 
               ->withProjects($projects);
}
```

And in the view :

```
<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id', 'order' => 'desc'])}}">Order by ID</a>
```

Comment: Hi Friend, I think I really need your help @Maraboc can we speak please?

Comment: hi @LluísPuigFerrer , i'm here :) is there a problem ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149687/discussion-between-maraboc-and-lluis-puig-ferrer